# How to implement attribute level mask depending on the Roles in loopback.js?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have few roles created in loopback application. Is there any way in which i can hide some property of the model depending on the Roles of the User?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a function and in that function based on the role of the user, you can delete some specific fields. This function should be called after each remote method that you want to apply this rule (You can use * to apply this function after all the remote methods).

Here is a sample code that I hope it helps you:

```
const filterBasedOnRole= function (ctx, remoteMethodOutput, next) {
    const RoleMapping = SampleModel.app.loopback.RoleMapping;
    if (ctx.req.accessToken && ctx.req.accessToken.userId) {
      RoleMapping.findOne({
        where: { principalId: ctx.req.accessToken.userId },
        include: 'role',
      }, (err, roleMapping) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!roleMapping) {
          //User doesn't have a role
        } else {
          const role = roleMapping.role().name;
          if (role === 'admin') {
             // Remove some fields from remoteMethodOutput
          }
        }
        next();
      });
    } else {
      // This user is not logged in, So it is a guest!
      next();
    }
};

SampleModel.afterRemote('search', filterBasedOnRole);  // Search is an example method, you can use whatever you want!
```